# javascript variable in input value

Tags: javascript

I have some problem.
This is my code snippets :

```
FB.api('/me', function(me){
  if (me.id) {
  alert(me.id);
  //alert(me.email);
  var fbmail = me.email;
  alert(fbmail);
  document.write('<input id="mail" type="hidden" value="'+fbmail+'">');                    
  var retro = document.getElementById('mail').value;
  alert(retro);                    
})
```

My problem is that there is no alert(retro); :(
Can you tell me what's wrong???

Comment: Sorry about my ignorance, but what is FB?

Answer (score 2):

`document.write` can only be used while the page is loading.

Calling it in an async callback will erase the current page, so `getElementById` will return null.

Comment: Thanx for all of your answer. I'm always searching for a solution.